# YoY & YTD - Taking into account the timestamp, as well as date, on records in the previous year

Tags: sql, datetime, parameters

My question is, what do I need to change in the WHERE clause for the SP to take into account the timestamp, as well as the date itself, on the CreatedDate field. For example...If the report was run at 1pm today, it would only bring back records made up to 1pm today this time last year [2015] and obviously all records created in 2016 so far. At present, 2015 is bringing back all records up to the end of the day. Any help would be much appreciated. Claire

```
@CreatedFrom15 DateTime = NULL,
@CreatedTo15 DateTime = NULL,
@CreatedFrom16 DateTime = NULL,
@CreatedTo16 DateTime = NULL,


SELECT

BookingID,
CreatedYear,
CreatedDate,
NightDuration,
HolidayCost,
TRAVPropertyTypeCategory

FROM Vw_TRAVLodgeResortGlampingFinancialByNights

WHERE 
((CreatedYear = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())-1 AND CreatedDate BETWEEN @CreatedFrom15 AND @CreatedTo15) AND (CreatedDate  >= @CreatedFrom15 OR @CreatedFrom15 IS NULL) AND (CreatedDate <= @CreatedTo15 OR @CreatedTo15 IS NULL)
OR
(CreatedYear = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AND CreatedDate BETWEEN @CreatedFrom16 AND @CreatedTo16) AND (CreatedDate  >= @CreatedFrom16 OR @CreatedFrom16 IS NULL)AND(CreatedDate <= @CreatedTo16 OR @CreatedTo16 IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

can you specify the dates of the parameters?
anyhow, the reference to the year seems unnecessary and also you can include the null case inside the between like this-
where CreatedDate between isnull(@createdFrom16,'20160101') and isnull(@CreatedTo16,'20161231')

Comment: I built the parameters the way I did in order to give the user the ability to change the From and To Dates on both years. So if they wanted to see all bookings made in 2015 between 2015-10-01 & 2015-10-18 and wanted to compare exactly the same time period in 2016 they could. If there is a better way of doing this, your help would be much appreciated?

Comment: I wanted the values of the parameters to see if you're missing something there, because the where close seems perfectly OK. I think a null value in the between can make a problem. maybe it's better to get only 2 parameters and use local variables for last year.